# How can I specify all `.jar` files under a directory to the option -cp` of `javac` ( and `java`)

Tags: java, bash

In bash, I would like to specify all `.jar` files under a directory to the option `-cp` of `javac` (and later `java` when running the compiled program).

But

```
$ javac  -cp /home/hibernate-release-4.3.11.Final/lib/required/*.jar *.java
javac: invalid flag: /home/hibernate-release-4.3.11.Final/lib/required/dom4j-1.6.1.jar
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
```

Is it because the expansion of `*.jar` files are  separated by  but not `:` which is required by `-cp`?

Is there a way that works without me to manually specify all the `.jar` files under a directory?

Thanks.

Comment: I suspect your question can be answered using the duplicate link.  If not, then edit your question and tell us where you got stuck.

Comment: If your shell expands the `*` as a shell wildcard (globbing), you need to quote it.  (Standard Posix Shell behaviour ...)